# Core Data setValue for Multiple Attributes at once

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, kvc

I have a Book entity in Core Data and a Book class acting as the model layer.

My Book model has multiple attributes. When comes the time to persist the books in Core Data, I would like to store them without having to do

```
bookObject.setValue(book.title , forKey: "name")
bookObject.setValue(book.author , forKey: "author")
bookObject.setValue(book.datePublished , forKey: "datePublished")
etc...
```

Is there a method akin to setValue for setting multiple CoreData Entity attributes at once ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* the `Book` model class inherits from `NSObject` *and* uses the
same property names and types as the Core Data entity *then* you can use
Key-Value Coding:

```
let keys = ["title", "author", "datePublished"]
let dict = book.dictionaryWithValuesForKeys(keys)
bookObject.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(dict)
```